# Can not send data to server with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

I want to pass 2 strings to the server but nothing worked for me. Please help!

```html
function test(email,msg){
    $.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : JSON.stringify({"email":email,"msg":msg}),
    });
}
test("fabian.oby@gmail.com","test 123")
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $msg = $_POST['email'];
    test(json_decode($email),json_decode($msg));
}
    
function test($email,$msg){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$email.'");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
}
```

Comment: does your API work as intended? like does it throws back json or some data? can you share API url?

Comment: I am not using any API. Or at least i dont know about it

Comment: where you are writin this php code?

Comment: I'm using xampp

Comment: Is your php code and ajax code on same page?

Comment: index.php file which calls the ajax, and the server.php that contains the isset part. I addded 'server.php' to the url in ajax

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  // url
       { "myData": 'This is my data.' }, // data to be submit
       function(data, status, xhr) {   // success callback function
                alert('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
       'json');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Read more about this method  at:  [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: does not work :( its not alerting the strings

Answer (score 0):

The test function is not calling in the server.php file

js.js:

```html
function test(email,msg){
    $.post('server.php',
       { "email":email, "msg":msg },
       function() {
                alert('succes');
            },
       'json');
}
test("fabian.oby@gmail.com","test \n 123")
```

server.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    test("test");
}

function test($email){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$email.'");</script>';
}
```

?>

Comment: do not write question as answer